# Cannot write to a remote file system in java

Tags: java, file-io, playframework

I'm using Play! framework. I want to access remote file (read & write) connected through LAN. While accessing to read a file for a first time in java. I was unable to read the file. If i load the URL in browser once (successfully) then i am able to read the file in java too. ( I am reading using HttpURLConnection) Now i want to write into the file which i can't. There are no errors or exceptions. But the content is not written to the file. I have given 777 permission to my Play! application. What could be the issue. How can i solve it.

EDIT:

To update the file i have written this code

```
public void createFileInPath(String filePath, Object contents)
   {
        try{

        Writer output = null;
        String text = contents.toString();
        File file = new File(filePath);
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        output.write(text);
        output.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error While Creating File in FileManager.java: " + e);
        }
   }
```

Comment: check for proper flush/stream close would be my first guess. Post the code for further help.

Comment: Are you committing the data you write in stream? closing the stream automatically does that

Comment: "Remote file", accessed through what kind of filesystem? NFS? SMB? CIFS? SSHFS? AFS? AFP? NCP? Coda? Intermezzo? S3? Lustre?

Comment: @sarnold whatever filesystem it is i should read

Comment: @saury i am closing the writer. I have pasted the code now. Pl check is that correct

Comment: @Nrj i updated the question with the code

Comment: Did you try mounting the network folder containing files on Samba server ? This will open the gate of accessing thee files in remote folder as you access/write the files locally.

Answer (score 0):

Try using java.io.* classes. You dont have to treat it specially if it is already mounted on your system (linux) or mapped(windows).

All you need to do is pass the right path and operate as if it is a local file.

To read a file:

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my file path"));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
    // To write into a file
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("my file path"));
    out.println("some content");
    out.flush(); // required to flush the content to filesystem
    out.close();
```

Comment: If you want to read and write then use this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Comment: If you want to deal with objects instead of strings then use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

Comment: I have given http:/localhost:9000/public/CacheLayer/Customer_Bmtech/UsersList/UsersList.list which is opening in browser but throws FileNotFoundException occured : http:/localhost:9000/public/CacheLayer/Customer_Bmtech/UsersList/UsersList.list (No such file or directory)

Comment: `replace localhost with your ip address` in http:/localhost:9000/public/CacheLayer/Customer_Bmtech/UsersList/UsersList.list

Comment: Uhhh.... are you really trying to "open" an HTTP resource using the _file_ IO classes?

Comment: @Hemant Metalia I have given ip of my system but same exception is being thrown